# NuGet Package Manager Console Default Project dropdown is empty

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-5

I recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2012 RTM Ultimate from MSDN.  I'm using EF Code First Migrations to build my database in my app, and I recently added a new entity and want to scaffold the migration for it.

To do this, you need to open the Package Manage Console window in VS, and type `add-migration "some name here"`.  This will scaffold any changes to your database since the last time it was updated.

---

## The Problem

**This issue did not occur on VS 2012 RC**

The problem I'm encountering is the "Default Project" dropdown in the Package Manager Console is not populated, despite having several projects in my solution.  The default project that is used when I just type the command above is the wrong project (my migrations are in another project).  I get the following error when I do this:

> No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'ProjectA'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).

[image: Visual Studio 2012 Package Manager Console]

---

## What I've Tried

I have tried setting the correct project (ProjectB) as the startup project, only to get this error:

> Could not load assembly 'ProjectA'. (If you are using Code First Migrations inside Visual Studio this can happen if the startUp project for your solution does not reference the project that contains your migrations. You can either change the startUp project for your solution or use the -StartUpProjectName parameter.)

---

## The Question

How can I manually specify which project migrations are added to, or force the Default Project dropdown to populate?

Comment: You can run `get-Help Add-Migration` to get full help for the command. The command supports `-ProjectName` and `-StartUpProjectName`. Try to use them. I'm not sure if this help you because those empty drop downs are strange. Also try restarting VS / closing and opening Package manager if you didn't try it yet.

Comment: -StartupProjectName should do the trick. I have the same issue: the dropdown is empty

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was able to manually specify the project by using the following:

```
add-migration "Locations" -StartupProjectName "ProjectA" -ProjectName "ProjectB"
```

The documentation for this command is sparse, so here's what I assume is happening:

1. `-StartupProjectName` specifies the project where the database configuration is stored (an MVC4 project in my case)
2. `-ProjectName` specifies the project where the migrations are to be scaffolded.

I had `ProjectB` set as the startup project in my app due to testing for this question, but I think you can omit `-StartupProjectName` if the correct project is set as a startup project in VS.

Answer (score 21):

In VS 2015, I just restarted the IDE and the dropdown was filled again.

Comment: Same worked for me. For some reason my drop-down went empty at some point whilst everything was open - nothing drastic seemed to change. Went to run an `update-database` for EF and got the "EntityFramework Package is not installed in project ''" message. Restarted VS2015 and all back to normal. Weird

Comment: Same for VS2019

Answer (score 4):

Close the IDE and open again may help. It worked on my VS2015

Answer (score 2):

Close the solution and open it again. Closing IDE sometimes takes more time. This works in VS 2017

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is experiencing this issue with Visual Studio 2019 and .NET Core projects this is because the interface lacks a method of adding solution files to the project.

I was able to resolve the issue by using the command line tool as follows:

First navigate to the folder that holds the project and open a (git) **bash** console window.

Then add a solution file to the folder.

```
dotnet new sln
```

Then add a reference to each project to the solution (* will find all solutions)

```
dotnet sln *.sln add <project-folder-1>/<project-name-1>.csproj
dotnet sln *.sln add <project-folder-2>/<project-name-2>.csproj
```

N.B. Remember to replace the project folder and the name with what you need.

Close Visual Studio 2019 and reopen.

Nuget Package Manager and console will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I had to open the solution.

To view to the solutions, look at the bottom of the "Solution Explorer" pane. There should be a "Team Explorer" tab. Click it. Then in the bottom half of the pane, your solutions should be listed. Double-click on the solution that you want to install things for, or right-click on it and select "Open".

That should open up the Package Manager Console with the correct project pre-selected.

Answer (score 1):

I had to Restore NuGet packages first.  Then it showed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Visual Studio 2013.  Right clicking on [Solution]->[Properties]->[Startup Project] make sure [Single startup project] is selected.  I previously had multiple projects selected for Azure worker role testing.

After existing VS, Package manager worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

first close vs,
then go to setting of your computer, apps & features, microsoft-visual-studio-installer,
modify, In the second tab you will get an option to define which parts of vs you want to use, select whatever belong to nuget.
when it is finished, open the vs again. now  it is supposed to work
success!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can select the projects under the [Solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgfR7.png) .Then it showed up on package manager console . It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when you use **Folder View** in **Solution Explorer** instead of the **solution** that you work on. I feel like that's the reason why people think it's fixed when they restart the IDE. It just switches back to solution I guess.

So just switch from Folder View to Solution View and then it'll probably work.

Answer (score -1):

If you see projects under Solution explorer, but default project dropdown is empty, then **my 100% precise solution** is:

1. Select all projects under Solution explorer, right click, and **REMOVE**
2. Click in **SAVE ALL**
3. Now, select Solution explorer and **ADD each project to Solution again**

After that, You will see all projects added in Package Manager Console's Default Project DropDown.

That's it.