# The term 'add-migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

So randomly from one day to the next my migrations stopped working. I do add-migration and it says its not being recognized. I'm using PM since this is a asp.net mvc and was working the day before.

> add-migration : The term 'add-migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

[image]

Comment: I'm suspicious that your Default project: dropdown is empty. It should be enabled so long as you have a project open, so try selecting the project with your EF stuff in it from there and then running `Add-Migration` again.

Comment: Thank you Kirk for reaching out. After reviewing the default project in the drop down its empty even though my project is open which shows in solution explorer...  SO basically there is nothing selected in the default project.

Comment: How can I go about this to fix this?

Comment: @RichardJimenez Did you find a solution to this? 

On Visual Studio 2019(enterprise preview), I have the same issue. I've restarted Visual Studio several times, updated it to the latest preview 3.0 and also installed Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise and 2017 Enterprise. None of the Solutions in these Comments nor the answer itself Solves this problem. 

I'm actually getting I'm actually getting [this repo][1] from github

  [1]: https://github.com/csharpfritz/Quiltoni.PixelBot

Answer (score 64):

This isn't exactly the issue the OP is having, but for dotnet core at least, this can also be caused by not having the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` nuget package installed, which is used for the package manager commands in Visual Studio and command line.

Comment: after installing "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" I had to restart the Visual Studio then it worked

Comment: Did not need to restart with VS2022

Comment: I can confirm that restarting VS2022 solved this problem for me too. Closing and reopening the solution did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 12):

What I had to do...

1) Tools -> Nuget Package Manger -> Package Manager Settings

2) General Tab

3) Clear All NuGet Cache(s)

4) Restart Visual Studio

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem, and simply closing the Package Manager Console, then restarting Visual Studio fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your default project needs to be set, as Kirk Larkin mentioned in the comments. Click the drop down list on default project and set it to which ever project you have entity framework installed on.

[image]

Also this link might help if your default project drop down list won't populate
[NuGet Package Manager Console Default Project dropdown is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028457/nuget-package-manager-console-default-project-dropdown-is-empty)

Hope this helps! If not let me know and I'll remove the answer(I had to use an answer because I can't comment under 50 rep) Cheers!

Comment: Can you explain this code? add-migration "Locations" -StartupProjectName "ProjectA" -ProjectName "ProjectB"

Comment: It's not really code to start off, it's a command to manually add the migration. So you would type that into the package manager console. "Locations" is where the project lives, "StartupProjectName" would be which project you want to use as your startup project, then just list the projects you want to get the changes from. Sorry if this isn't very clear I've never had this problem with entity framework so I've never had to use this manual command. Another thing that wasn't mentioned is try saving everything restarting Visual Studio and if that doesn't work try restarting your whole PC

Comment: Also don't forget to accept the answer if this resolves your problem so it doesn't keep showing up as unanswered on the questions search.

Comment: So for location will I have to clarify c drive desktop etc? or just the folder name where the project lives? Which in my case is a folder called Projects in my documents. The project name is GigHub inside projects. Im still quit confuse sorry btw.

Comment: after running its still saying add-migration is not being recognized. The term 'add-migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling 
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: If add-migration is not being recognized I would try restarting your Visual Studio or whichever IDE you are using. Other than that I would assume "Location" would be a relative path from where the solution lives. Also make sure you have entity framework installed properly and try the PMC command update-packages -reinstall, that will update and overwrite the old packages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151634/discussion-between-richard-jimenez-and-chase).

Comment: On Visual Studio 2019(enterprise preview), I have the same issue. I've restarted visual Studio several times, updated it to the latest preview 3.0 and also installed Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise and 2017 Enterprise. None of the Solutions in these Comments nor the answer itself Solves this problem. 

I'm actually getting a repo from github with about 250 stars and 100 forks(by a Microsoft PM)!

Comment: On Visual Studio 2019(enterprise preview), I have the same issue. I've restarted Visual Studio several times, updated it to the latest preview 3.0 and also installed Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise and 2017 Enterprise. None of the Solutions in these Comments nor the answer itself Solves this problem. 

I'm actually getting I'm actually getting [this repo][1] from github

  [1]: https://github.com/csharpfritz/Quiltoni.PixelBot

Comment: What exactly are you typing into the console because this isn't an issue about repos or GitHub. It's about an issue with add-migration not working for projects using entity framework.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, also we get the same error when "add-migration", i try one solution which is update Package Manager by using follow step

1. In Visual Studio, from the "Tools" menu choose the "Extensions and Updates" option.
2. From the dialog that appears, expand the "Updates" node from the tree at the left side.
3. Select the "Visual Studio Gallery" option from the tree.
4. Finally, look for the Package Manager update in the list of updates at the right side 
   of the dialog and click the "Update" button beside it.

it is approx 5 - 10 MB update, after update complete try Get-Help Add-Migration

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler for me, just re-starting VS2017 fixed this. Not had it until I got VS2017 professional, so this may be an issue for others in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the nuget console, check if you have a right project selected as default.
2. Set this project as a startup project

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Nuget package manager and it worked for me. Fist I uninstalled the previous version, 2.0.x, then installed version 2.8.x

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue in Visual Studio for Mac then simply re-install **Nuget Package Manager Console** extension. It will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.
so, in your console where you see default project(dropdown), make sure your current project is selected a most importantly check that the package source(dropdown) is selected as nuget.org