# Your startup project 'project' doesn't reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

Tags: entity-framework, nuget-package

I'm building WPF application with the EntityFrameworkCore version 2.2.2

However, when i want to `Add-Migration` it output me an error...

`Your startup project 'project' doesn't reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. This package is required for the Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your startup project is correct, install the package, and try again.`

I don't know why this is happen, because I can use it before this error come up.

This is my `packages.config` file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Costura.Fody" version="3.3.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Fody" version="4.0.2" targetFramework="net461" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net461" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Remotion.Linq" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" version="1.1.12" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.core" version="1.1.12" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.linux" version="1.1.12" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.osx" version="1.1.12" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.v110_xp" version="1.1.12" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.net45" version="1.1.12" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Immutable" version="1.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Interactive.Async" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

The package is already installed.

[image: NuGet Package Manager]

Thanks a lot for any helps.

Comment: right click on your project, choose `Manage nuget packages`, go to `Browse`, search for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` and make sure it is installed.

Comment: @Masoud Keshavarz I checked and it has been installed..

Comment: Do you have multiple projects in your solution? You must set your `Model` as start up project, which has `DBContext` class in it. Also choose `Model` as default project in `Package Manager Console`

Comment: @Masoud Keshavarz I have only 1 project in my solution. Tried all the thing you said and still not working... . I tried create a new project, and not working too...

Comment: @MasoudKeshavarz do you think that reinstall visual studio can solved it?

Comment: No its irrelevant, perhaps its better idea to install `dotnet core sdk`

Comment: @MasoudKeshavarz I think i foudn the problem. I have installed Fody package for the Costura.Fody , after i uninstall the Fody i work like normal...

Answer (score 7):

`Add-Migration` may be getting confused since you are using Costura to embed assemblies. Try removing costura to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: #$&&$*&$** i just spent 3 freaking hours on this and it was Costura!!!!,!

Comment: @ChristopherKelly sorry to hear that. happy to accept a PR that makes this scenario work

Answer (score 5):

I did install it using this command and it works !

I'm using .net core version 3.1.1

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design --version 3.1.1
```

Comment: Great it works for me :) Just adapt with the right `--version` according to the `youproject.context.csproj `

Answer (score 4):

Install it again using PMC and then it will find the reference:

```
PM> dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

Comment: What is PMC? Could you please expand?

Comment: Oh, I see, you mean "Package Manager Console". Those who are not used to this environment have difficulties decoding acronyms (that didn't work in my case, however).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same Problem.
You have to change startup project.
**Whichever project you want to migrate, make it a startup project.** Then set as package manager console default project.
Finally, you can add migration. Like : `add-migration initial`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your startup project 'Lmss.Web' doesn't reference *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design*. This package is required for the Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your startup project is correct, install the package, and try again.
[image]

During the migration, this error shows you need to install *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design* in your startup project. This will help you to run the migration.

Install this:
[image]